# How can I scan for generic interfaces?

Tags: c#, generics

I am managing different types of products and I am getting their information from different manufacturers' APIs. They share some common properties, so I decided to make the type be generic:

```
public class Product<T> where T : class, new() {
  public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
  public T ProductInfo { get; set; } = new T();
}
```

My application will be getting a list of productDTOs whose details I will need to retrieve from different places. I decided to create an interface that each `ProductRetriever` will implement. I will ask each `ProductRetriever` if they can retrieve the information. If it can, I will call its `Retrieve` method.

Since each `ProductRetriever` will be returning the specific `ProductInfo` for the `Product<T>`, I decided to make it a generic interface:

```
public interface IProductRetriever<TProductInfo> where T : class, new() {
  Task<bool> CanRetrieve(ProductCategoryEnum productCategory);
  Task<Product<TProductInfo>?> Retrieve(ProductDto dto);
}
```

I've implemented several `ProductRetriever`s which I've manually called one at a time and they work fine. For example:

```
var manufacturerOneRetriever = new ManufacturerOneRetriever<Product1>();
if(manufacturerOneRetriever.CanRetrieve(ProductCategoryEnum.Automotive)) {
   var product = manufacturerOneRetriever.Retrieve(productDto);
}
```

Now, I would like to scan the assembly searching for the classes that implement the `IProductRetriever<TProductInfo>` and call them.

Before I had the generic interface, I was able to scan the assembly and register the `ProductRetrievers` with the container:

```
using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .ConfigureServices(services => {
    var iProductRetrievers = typeof(IProductRetriever).Assembly.GetTypes()
      .Where(x => x is { IsAbstract: false, IsClass: true } && x.GetInterface(nameof(IProductRetriever)) == typeof(IProductRetriever));

    foreach (var rule in iProductRetrievers) {
      services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(IProductRetriever), rule, ServiceLifetime.Transient));
    }
  })
  .Build();
```

Now that I have it as a generic interface, I am getting an error in the generic portion of `x.GetInterface(nameof(IProductRetriever<>))` in:

```
.Where(x => x is { IsAbstract: false, IsClass: true } && x.GetInterface(nameof(IProductRetriever<>)) == typeof(IProductRetriever<>))
```

Comment: Why are you using the `new()` constraint? Requiring a parameterless constructor for `T` means that if `T` has any state or class-invariants then the `T` object will exist in a potentially invalid state. Is there a reason you can't use a caller-provided `Func<T>` factory instead of calling `new T()` ?

Comment: IIRC, you can't use "open" generic types with `x.GetInterface(nameof(IProductRetriever<>)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`GetInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getinterface?view=net-7.0#system-type-getinterface(system-string))

> **Note**
>
> For generic interfaces, the name parameter is the mangled name, ending
> with a grave accent (`` ` ``) and the number of type
> parameters. This is true for both generic interface definitions and
> constructed generic interfaces. For example, to find `IExample<T>` or
> `IExample<string>`, search for `` "IExample`1" ``.

Unlike `typeof`, `nameof` cannot be used with an open generic type like `IProductRetriever<>`. Even if you pass in a constructed type, it will only evaluate to the simple name of the generic type, without the `` `1 `` part.

You can either use a string literal, or `typeof(IProductRetriever<>).Name` instead.

Also note that `GetInterface` returns a constructed type, with the type parameters filled in, so you can't directly compare it to `typeof(IProductRetriever<>)`. You should get its generic type definition first:

```
x.GetInterface("IProductRetriever`1").GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IProductRetriever)
```

I'm not sure how `ServiceDescriptor` works, but if it needs a constructed generic type too, you would need to use the return value of `GetInterface` again. You would pass in

```
rule.GetType().GetInterface("IProductRetriever`1")
```